# How can I use initialValue for DatePicker in Form.Item of Ant Design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Ant Design says I can't use `defaultValue` if I wrapped it with `Form.Item` with `name`.

https://ant.design/components/form/

```
After wrapped by Form.Item with name property, value(or other property defined by valuePropName) onChange(or other property defined by trigger) props will be added to form controls, the flow of form data will be handled by Form which will cause:

You shouldn't use onChange on each form control to collect data(use onValuesChange of Form), but you can still listen to onChange.

You cannot set value for each form control via value or defaultValue prop, you should set default value with initialValues of Form. Note that initialValues cannot be updated by setState dynamiclly, you should use setFieldsValue in that situation.
```

So I set `initialValues` to `Form` component and I got this error when I use Form with DatePicker.

```
moment.js:93 Uncaught TypeError: date.clone is not a function
    at Object.format (moment.js:93)
    at useValueTexts.js:13
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at useValueTexts.js:12
    at useMemo (useMemo.js:6)
    at useValueTexts (useValueTexts.js:7)
    at InnerPicker (Picker.js:158)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14803)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17482)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18596)
```

My code is like this.
`worker` object has a `dateOfBirth` which is ISOString.

```js
const dateFormat = 'YYYY/MM/DD';

return (
  <Form
    layout="vertical"
    hideRequiredMark
    onFinish={values => onFinish(values)}
    initialValues={worker}
  >
    <Form.Item
      label="Date Of Birth"
      name="dateOfBirth"
    >
      <DatePicker format={dateFormat} />
    </Form.Item>
  </Form>
);
```

How can I get and use default value of worker's dateOfBirth?
Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `initialValue` of the `DatePicker` component must be a `moment` object. You will need to convert `dateOfBirth` field on the `worker` object from an ISOString to a moment object as illustrated below:

```js
const dateFormat = "YYYY/MM/DD";

const worker = {
  dateOfBirth: moment('2020-06-09T12:40:14+0000')
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Form
    layout="vertical"
    hideRequiredMark
    onFinish={values => onFinish(values)}
    initialValues={worker}
  >
    <Form.Item label="Date Of Birth" name="dateOfBirth">
      <DatePicker format={dateFormat} />
    </Form.Item>
  </Form>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

CodeSandbox Link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/antdesign-setting-initialvalue-on-datepicker-inside-form-ypi4u?file=/index.js:239-652

Comment: Its kinda harsh that these Components that expect a specific class instance for their values don't have a "transform" function prop to be able to do this internally :/